# Place equal elements in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have an array. I sorted it, so I have sorted array and indeces of sorted elements in the initial array.

Fo example, from `[4 5 4 4 4 4 5 4]` I got `[4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5]` and `[1 3 4 5 6 8 2 7]`.

How to place recieved indeces in a cell array, so that in one cell will be indeces of equal elements? For my example, it will be: `{1 3 4 5 6 8}`, `{2 7}`.

I'm searching for non-loop way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
x = [4 5 4 4 4 4 5 4]; %// data

[~, ~, jj] = unique(x);
result = accumarray(jj(:), 1:numel(x), [], @(v) {v(:).'});
```

Or, if you need each set of indices sorted:

```
result = accumarray(jj(:), 1:numel(x), [], @(v) {sort(v(:)).'});
```

Comment: Got a question - Doesn't `accumarray` has looping inside it?

Comment: @Divakar Good question. I don't know. I wouldn' be surprised if it does (in the same sense as `arrayfun` etc are loops in disguise). But it's so useful I wouldn't mind :-)

Comment: I think it has looping, but these functions are good "wrapers" to hide looping. Also, in this particular case, I don't think vectorization stands any chance. Working with cellarrays brings those limitations I think. +1 BTW

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. Yes, cell arrays don't get on well with vectorization