# Cell of grouped elements

Tags: matlab, cell, grouping

I have a linked list S with S(i)=s_i and S(i) is a non-negative integer number.
I want a cell C=C{0+1},...C{max(S)+1} such that C{i+1}={i_1,...,i_k}, S(i_1)=...=S(i_k)=i and k is maximal. 
Example:

```
S(1)=0,S(2)=0,S(3)=1,S(4)=2,S(5)=1,S(6)=2,S(7)=6,
```

Then I should get

```
 C{0+1}={1,2}, C{1+1}={3,5}, C{2+1}={4,6}, C{3+1}={},...C{6+1}={7}, C{7+1}={}
```

How can I do that as fast as possible in matlab ?

I already found

[Place equal elements in cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426139/place-equal-elements-in-cell-array)

However, I also need the empty sets like in C{3+1}.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood; `C{2+1}` should be `[4,6]`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done very easily with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
C = accumarray(S(:)+1, 1:numel(S), [], @(x) {sort(x.')});
```

---

Here's an alternative with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
t = bsxfun(@eq, S(:), 0:max(S));
s = sum(t, 1);
t = bsxfun(@times, t, (1:numel(S)).');
C = mat2cell(nonzeros(t).', 1, s);
```